# Angular 2 - HTML inside variable will not display properly

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have written a block of HTML that I need be able to render dynamically. As is, the HTML works like I want it to and displays what I expect to see. Here is the HTML, which is inside of a  element:

```
<div style="width: 550px;">
    <div style="height: 40px; float: left; width: 25%;" >
        <ul data-dropdown data-value class='bx--dropdown' tabindex='0'>
            <li class='bx--dropdown__menu-text'>HTTP</li>
            <li>
                <svg class='bx--dropdown__arrow'>
                    <use xlink:href='/assets/img/bluemix-icons.svg#caret--down'></use>
                </svg>
            </li>
            <li>
                <ul class='bx--dropdown__list'>
                    <li data-option data-value='grpc' class='bx--dropdown__list-item'><a class='bx--dropdown__link' href='javascript:void(0)'>gRPC</a></li>
               </ul>
           </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div style="height: 40px; float: left; margin-left: 10px; width: 60%;">
        <input id='text1' type='text' class='bx--text__input' placeholder='Hint text here'>
    </div>
    <div style="float: left; margin-top: 5px; width: 10%;">
        <button style="height: 40px" data-copy-btn class='bx--btn--copy'>
            Copy
            <svg class='bx--btn--right-icon__icon'>
                <use class='bx--btn--right-icon__use' xlink:href='/assets/img/bluemix-icons.svg#copy--code'></use>
            </svg>
            <div class='bx--btn--copy__feedback' data-feedback='Copied!'></div>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

My function to store it in the typescript file is just a return statement with all the html as a string.

```
packageProtocolColumn() {
        return '<div style="width:550px;"><div style="height:40px; float:left;width:25%;">' +
                '<ul data-dropdown data-value class="bx--dropdown" tabindex="0"><li class="bx--dropdown__menu-text">HTTP</li>' +
                '<li><svg class="bx--dropdown__arrow"><use xlink:href="/assets/img/bluemix-icons.svg#caret--down"></use>' +
                '</svg></li><li><ul class="bx--dropdown__list"><li data-option data-value="grpc" class="bx--dropdown__list-item">' +
                '<a class="bx--dropdown__link" href="javascript:void(0)">gRPC</a></li></ul></li></ul></div><div style="height: 40px;' +
                'float:left;margin-left:10px;width:60%;"><input id="text1" type="text" class="bx--text__input" placeholder="Hint text here">' +
                '</div><div style="float: left;margin-top:5px;width:10%;"><button style="height:40px" data-copy-btn class="bx--btn--copy">' +
                'Copy<svg class="bx--btn--right-icon__icon"><use class="bx--btn--right-icon__use" xlink:href="/assets/img/bluemix-icons.svg#copy--code">' +
                '</use></svg><div class="bx--btn--copy__feedback" data-feedback="Copied!"></div></button></div></div>';
}
```

I call the function in the typescript file, make the html available to the loop and then render it as follows:

```
<td *ngFor="let column of row; let colIndex=index"><div [innerHtml]="column"></div></td>
```

All other columns render correctly and this one partially renders but not fully. I have compared the output html, taken from Chrome's debugger, with my hand written html using Beyond Compare and aside from the single quotes ' ' vs double quotes " ", due to tslint settings, they appear to be identical.

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong? If I can't solve this then I will have to create this table at least twice and I prefer to take full advantage of Angular 2 so that I will only need to create it once.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where is `row` in *ngFor? What is the relevance of `row` and `packageProtocolColumn()`?

Comment: The row object contains the columns from all the rows. Each row object contains all the properties for the columns in that row. The packageProtocolColumn() returns an html string that I want to use as a cell column. Row is taken from an outer *ngFor loop inside of a <tr> element.

Comment: Then why you don't assign `[innerHtml]="packageProtocolColumn()"`?

Comment: The column is an element of an array where that html is a single column. I'll add a condition and try it though.